# Can't login Ubuntu

Tags: login, environment-variables, username, switch-user

I copied all Ubuntu system files to /home/ubuntu to obtain full Ubuntu operate system in Termux.

The Ubuntu system has a user with password.
Termux is an app that provide part of Linux environment.

I use code below to start Ubuntu.

```
proot -0 -r ~/ubuntu -b /dev/ -b /sys/ -b /proc/ -b $HOME 
/usr/bin/env -i HOME=/home/wedge TERM="$TERM" PS1='[termux@ubuntu W]$ ' PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games 
/bin/login
```

However, I can't login to system with correct username and password.

I try to solve the problem by using `/bin/bash --login` instead of `/bin/login` . It will show errors below but I can access the system.

```
groups: cannot find name for group ID 9997
groups: cannot find name for group ID 50121
```

I now login with root account, but files seem read-only for me.

**What should I do to login?**

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: What do you mean, you installed Ubuntu in another Linux system? Please [edit] your question and explain what you did, and what you're trying to do.

Comment: @CarlH I edited my question. Sorry for not stating the question clearly.

Comment: create new user with same username and pass

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou I can't make it. All files are read-only to me. I am not allowed to create a new user.

Comment: Control+Alt+F1 ? create new user with same username and pass using terminal. Then Control+Alt+F7 , logout , login to that user. Test it and tell us if you can login through that terminal interface

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou Here is what I Typed " adduser wedge" and It shows " the user 'wedge' already exits"

Comment: It's really wierd to not be able to login to that user since its there. Backup everything from that user and remove the user and recreate it. First test if you can login and then restore your files in the user and relog. ~EDIT: create another user in order to do that procedure , just in case one in a million you totally lose all your users and end up with only a terminal interface

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou The whole system is read-only to me as I said. Whoami shows that I am root but I cannot save changes. The root access is fake. Thus, I can't delete user or make backup. Another direction maybe.

Comment: what can is say then..... wierd....... is there a termux debug forum ? maybe there they can help since it's a termux problem

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou Thanks anyway. I will try more ways to solve it.